# How to create a Crypto Wallet Application?

Tags: wallets

**How to create a DAPP like Metamask but with others features?**

I've been thinking in a Decentralized Wallet which allows you to interact with others functionalities

**How do I get started?** I mean I mean what development resources do I need to create a browser wallet or a mobile application and create its system based on Smart Contract...

Comment: Metamask is an open source browser plugin https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/. You could start by reading their code.

Answer (score 0):

Web3js has everything you need to create it, security will be the hard part, it is relatively simple to create a wallet. You can use web3js and just do:

```
web3.eth.accounts.create()
```

To create a new wallet, see docs [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-accounts.html). Using this alongside [infura](https://infura.io/) is most likely what metamask does.

Comment: Alright thanks so much!!, I still have a question, once I crate an application system like metamask for interact with one dapp, the next part will be to create the user interface, in order to do that just create a font-end like tradicional applications or do I need something more?

Comment: @Satoshi_Amadeus_XDS_Stars You will need to make some sort of api to work with your wallet, like metamask has `request_accounts` so that the dapp can connect with your wallet